# Android: Draw vertical line in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to draw vertical line in a row layout of the list (Recycler View). The line should be align left of the layout with margin left 20dp and the line height should be auto, when the content of the row layout increase the vertical line align that align left of the layout also should increase.

I tried to add line by drawing the vertical line in drawable folder and add it to the background of the layout. But the problem is line comes only as the half

**Draw able : vertical_line.xml**

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="90"
android:toDegrees="90"
android:pivotX="10">
<shape
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ff00ff"
        />
</shape>
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/black_two">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/vertical_line"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I draw a line on the left of the layout with auto height?

Comment: Do you really a drawable xml to draw a vertical line? Because you can also do that with just views...

Comment: Your parent `RelativeLayout ` height is "wrap_content " change it to  "match_parent" so that it will draw a line on the whole screen

Comment: @ Aaron  if we use <View> how to make that height as wrap_content

Comment: @Akshay Katariya am using this layout as the row item of my list, so how can i change row parent layout to match_parent?. if so  1 Row consume full height of the view.

Comment: @BinilSurendran If you use <View>, just set the height to match_parent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `View` for vertical line instead of a shape:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="#ff00ff"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks man, I was tried same thing with the parent layout as < Relative Layout>, but as you said after change it to <Linear Layout> it is success.

Comment: You're welcome. If you change the `TextView` height to `wrap_content`, it will still work - the `View` height will be adjusted to match its parent, which is affected by the `TextView`.